# Executing compiler processes from the command line

Tags: debugging, cmd, compilation, ide

Some time ago I started a project, an IDE, and I spent some time thinking about how the compilation will work, and from what I have gathered as information, I can just download, let's say a C/C++ compiler like MinGW and run commands from the command line (cmd).

But is this the right approach for using compilers? Is there a more efficient way to implement and use a compiler into my software?

Also, how will the debugging part be done? Are there debuggers online which I can download and again run operations from the command line?

And in short, how would I implement such vital features into my software? (Compiling, debugging, maybe even code analysis)

Comment: StackOverflow is a place where programmers share troubled code. It wants specific questions with specific answers. SO avoids questions that lead to out-of-the-box, free-range comments. Those questions tend to lead to disagreement and bickering. You have great questions, but SO is not the best place to get answers.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the info, will have that in mind. Where can I get an answer to such a question?